# Retrieving Array of Object from params on Grails

Tags: arrays, ajax, grails

I'm passing an `Array` on a `POST` request using an `AJAX` call, but not a simple one, rather an `Array` of `Object`s:

```
var param = {
    ...,
    branches: {
        0: {
            address: "...",
            telephone: "...",
            fax: "...",
            ...
        },
        ...
        nth: {
            address: "...",
            telephone: "...",
            fax: "...",
            ...
        }
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".../saveTransaction"
    data: param
    success: function(r) {
        ...
    }
});
```

This is my `controller`

```
def orderService;
function saveTransaction() {
    def response = orderService.save(params)
    render response as JSON
}
```

And this is my `service`:

```
def save(params) {
    def branches = params.branches
    println "branches: $branches"

    def branches = params.list("branches")
    println "branches: $branches"

    branches = params.list("branches[]")
    println "branches: $branches"
}
```

It does not display what I expect, instead it displays the following:

```
branches: null
branches:
branches: []
```

How can I get these passed `branches` on the `service` from the `params` as an `Array` / `List`?

---

After experimenting, I've seen that it is not passed as an `object` rather as a flat `Map` having it's accessor as the `key`, so when I use:

```
println "branches: " + branches."[0][address]"
```

It prints:

```
branches: ...
```

Now, my follow-up question is how can I change this behavior to this instead?

```
println "branches: " + branches[0].address
```

Comment: Can you paste here the params that your getting in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Igor's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16685511/4043409), I changed my `AJAX` call, used the `JSON.stringify` function and `contentType` option:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: saveAgreementURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(r) {
    }
});
```

And on my `controller`, I used this:

```
def orderService;
function saveTransaction() {
    def response = orderService.save(request.JSON)
    render response as JSON
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you might want to use JSON format for your request, which is more appropriate for your data structure:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".../saveTransaction",
    dataType:'json',
    data: param     
});


class YourController {
  def save(){
    def json = request.JSON
    def list = json.branches
    service.save list
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. This doesn't work, just tested this today, `println "JSON: $json"` displays: `JSON: [:]`.

Comment: you request must be empty

Comment: How can you pass value to request? Isn't it just the same with `params` that is automatically generated when a request was made to the controller?